# How to stub Redis subscribe channel using Sinonjs?

Tags: node.js, sinon, stub

I have a simple pub/sub using Redis

```
const sub = redis.createClient()
sub.subscribe('my_channel')

// I would like to stub this on event, so I can pass an object to the msg argument
sub.on('message', (channel, msg) => {
    //parse the msg object
})
```

May I know how can I stub the `sub.on` event callback using Sinonjs, so I could pass an object (shown below) to the `msg` argument

```
{
    "name":"testing"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `callsArgWith` to achieve this.

```
// a mock callback function with same arguments channel and msg
var cb = function (channel, msg){
    console.log("this "+ channel + " is " + msg.name + "."); 
}

// a mock sub object with same member function on    
var sub = {
    on: function(event_name, cb){ console.log("on " + event_name) },
};

// FIRST: call the mock function
sub.on("message", cb("channel", {"name":"not stub"}));

// -----------------------------------------

// prepare mock arguments
var my_msg = {"name":"stub"}

// stub object
var subStub = sub;
sinon.stub(subStub);

// passing mock arguments into the member function of stub object
subStub.on.callsArgWith(1, 'channel', my_msg);

// SECOND: call the stub function
sub.on('message', cb);
```

**Results**

```
this channel is not stub.
on message
this channel is stub.
```

Note: Because the object is become stub, thus the `on message` will not show in the second call.

**[Edit]**

Since I do not have the same environment, I mock the redis-related code, if you need to use the above case in your code, you can try this.

```
const sub = redis.createClient()
sub.subscribe('my_channel')

var subStub = sub;
sinon.stub(subStub);
subStub.on.callsArgWith(1, 'my_channel', {"name":"testing"});

sub.on('message', (channel, msg) => {
    //parse the msg object
})
```

Comment: nice explaination, but i still cant figure it out how to stub the redis callback